# Start built in stopwatch using an android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, stopwatch

I am trying to start the stopwatch in the android clock app using an intent but I can't figure out how. I can successfully set an alarm as well as start a timer in the same app, but not the stopwatch. I using a Galaxy Note 3.

Comment: There is no built-in stopwatch on all ~2.5 billion Android devices, and there is no standard `Intent` structure for working with one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I find it strange that there is a stopwatch within the clock app but there is no intent for it, maybe the stopwatch is html embedded in the app it self. Alternatively i am thinking about downloading a third party stopwatch in order to use the intent the way i intended in the first place.

Comment: "I find it strange that there is a stopwatch within the clock app" -- there is no single "the clock app". There are ~26,000 Android device models. There are hundreds of different "clock apps" pre-installed on Android devices, and some devices that lack such an app entirely (e.g., Android TV). None of those clock apps have to offer a stopwatch feature.